# How to store a line in a text file into an array?

Tags: c#, text, line

I have a problem, which i cannot face with. I want the program (as seen below) to store all the line of the question located in "temp_q.txt" file. for example this is a question:

> C1: Who is John Smith?

And save the words of the question on an array, and then if it finds the answer in the "book" whitch I have named "core.txt" It will show the answer into textbox.2
Here is the part of the code:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\\Users\TEI\Desktop\temp_q.txt"))
        {
            //OK, pff..Now search for the question to answer!
            System.IO.StreamReader keytxt = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\TEI\Desktop\temp_q.txt");
            String line;
            while ((line = keytxt.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(textBox1.Text))    //If the question has been found...
                {
                    String ctrl1 = String.Empty;
                    ctrl1 = ("Line Found!Beginning Voice Transfer..");
                    richTextBox2.Text = ctrl1;
                    //Here i want to save the question word-by-word in an array.


                    //Begin searching for the right answer in the core



                }
            }
```

**Every little help is aprreciated!
Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 2):

For saving the question word by word into an array, you could just simple declare an array in your code and put the question into a `string` variable and ultimately use the `Split(' ')` function to split it into individual words. Something like this :

```
string question = "Who is John Smith?";
string[] words = new string[100];
words = question.Split(' ');
```

You can define the array-size as per your requirement here. This will break up the entire question by the `whitespaces` that are present in between the words.

**UPDATE : Finding the word in Core.txt part :**

Now when you want to search for some particular word in that text file, you can loop through the array that we have just made, one element at a time, searching for a match in your `line` object. Something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    if(line.Contains(words[i].ToString())) 
    {
      //put your logic here.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But, what about searching in the "core" using the array? Have you any ideas?

Comment: Is "core" a word that you want to search from that entire array ?

Comment: No "core" is a book, where the answer is located.

Comment: For example I want to search "John Smith" in the Core.txt..how to do this using the array you've just said.?

Comment: See my updated answer. I have put an idea regarding what you are asking.

Comment: But wait where you connect your for loop with the Core.txt? Wasn't I supposed to user stream reader first?

Comment: Well ofc, you first have to get the reader object first, to which you will compare the array elements in the loop.

Comment: sorry for being so annoying, but can you give me an example?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want to read the `Core.txt` file in your code, right ?

Comment: Well in that case, you can try using the same code that you are using to read the `temp_q.txt` file. That should get you through.